How to choose lowest number value from varchar record
How can i choose lowest number from this varchar column ?



Ranks




131,31,97,347,1


2,61


197,998,48,9


941,439,13



This is just example. I have table with around 12000 records and i need to choose lowest value from every record.
Table is varchar but values inside are numeric as you can see.

You should fix your data model and a) stop storing CSV values in a single row and also b) do not store numeric data as text.

You need to look into and understand data normalization. It is the basics for the relational database model. As a hint your data model violates 1st normal form. Normalization applied will result in the model  Tim Biegeleisen has suggested - at a minimum.

Remember that your current data model is slow by design.

When you use postgresql, you can simply do it. I will provide sample code.
select id, min(cast(unnset(string_to_array(ranks, ',')) as integer)) as lowest_value from your_table_name group by id;

The goal of the above code is to remove , in varchar values and convert the value to integer and then choose lowest value of the converted values. I hope it will helps you.

The simplest and most efficient approach for your case in PostgreSQL would be the one that uses unnest in combination with string_to_array.
SELECT id, MIN(CAST(value AS INT)) AS lowest_value FROM your_table_name, unnest(string_to_array(ranks, ',')) AS value GROUP BY id;

This query is straight forward, with just a few SQL functions (string_to_array, unnest, and MIN).
